# Workaround for CSS translation event listener firing when not wanted

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I am working on a website and have a series of transitions for a certain element on the page. I place a listener on my element with a callback for when it finishes it's first transition. The CSS for the first transition looks like this.

```
/* translation specs. for when the shape moves to the centre */
    -webkit-transition-property: left, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 3.0s, 3.0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s, 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-property: left, -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 3.0, 3.0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s, 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -ms-transformtransition-property: left, -webkit-transform;
    -ms-transformtransition-duration: 3.0s, 3.0s;
    -ms-transformtransition-delay: 0.2s, 0.2s;
    -ms-transformtransition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-property: left, transform;
    transition-duration: 3.0s, 3.0s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s, 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

The problem is that the transform ends before the left movement and multiple "transitionend" events happen. This wouldn't be a problem except for the fact that I put a new event listener on the shape (to listen for the transition of a class that I then add to it) immediately after the first "transitionend" event. Subsequently, the left "transitionend" triggers it. The only thing that I've been able to identify as a guard for this is something like the below in the callback in JS

```
shape.addEventListener('transitionend', function handler() {
        if (event.propertyName === "left") { return }
       // do actual stuff below this guard
       // ...
}
```

The problem is that I cannot use the "left" guard because I have other types of events that I need to trigger and their propertyName is "left" which is the same as the false positive event described above.

I looked through event's keys and I wasn't able to find anything that would help me distinguish it. Of course an ideal solution would be to add a key to the transition from the JS before it adding the classname to the element to trigger it but I don't know how to do that or if it's even possible. Other than that the only solution I can think of is a setTimeout() delay but that's sloppy and hacky and not something I particularly want to use.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a counter to keep track of which event you want to react to? This is assuming that the events always fire in the same order.

```
let counter = 0;
let targetTransitionIndex = X;
shape.addEventListener('transitionend', function handler() {
    if (counter == targetTransitionIndex) { 
   // do actual stuff below this guard
   // ...
    }
   couter++;
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it's a function which runs for different shapes and transitions and thus I would like something more general. I don't know if it will always be a certain index.